# Converting PostGIS empty geometry to NULL

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Is there a more succinct way to express this idea?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS null_if_empty(geometry);
CREATE FUNCTION null_if_empty(g geometry) RETURNS geometry AS $func$
    SELECT CASE WHEN ST_IsEmpty(g) THEN NULL ELSE g END;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: No, that is perfect.

Comment: I hate the verbosity of SQL. ._. `g => ST_IsEmpty(g) ? NULL : g`

Comment: @loop have you tried with `nullif`, e.g. for points `SELECT nullif(geom,'POINT EMPTY'::geometry) FROM t`?

Comment: @JimJones The type of the geometry may vary...

Comment: @loop in that case I believe your function is the most elegant way to make this check ;) +1

Comment: @JimJones Nothing in SQL is elegant. :'D

Comment: @loop well, one can argue about that. But one thing is for sure: it's really bulky :-D cheers